# how to load 2 fxml files in the same time

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have two javafx panes, "pane1" and "pane2" ("pane1" is the first parent of "pane2"). How can I load two fxml files, say "fxml1.fxml" and "fxml2.fxml" in the same time, loading "fxml1.fxml" in "pane1" and "fxml2.fxml" in "pane2" in the same time.

Here's what I've tried. But this loads only the fxml1.fxml file but doesn't load the fxml2.fxml file...

```
public class HostelController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Button hostlersBut;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }

    @FXML
    private void hostlersClkHostel(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            pane1.getChildren().clear();
            pane1.getChildren().add(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml1.fxml")));

            pane2.getChildren().clear();
            pane2.getChildren().add(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml2.fxml")));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.print(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

here's the current view's fxml file

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="anchorPane" prefHeight="508.0" prefWidth="968.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controllers.HostelController">
    <children>
      <Pane fx:id="pane1" prefHeight="538.0" prefWidth="1014.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="hostelersBut" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="100.0" onAction="#hostelAction" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Hostel"> </Button>
            <Pane fx:id="pane2" layoutX="166.0" prefHeight="538.0" prefWidth="846.0">
               <children>
               </children>
            </Pane>
         </children>
      </Pane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

this is a minimal code, there are some other buttons and so I can't use the initialize method to initialize one pane on load... As I said, only the first fxml file is loaded, the second doesn't...

Comment: Just the same way as you load one FXML file, except you do it twice... Post some code showing what you've tried.

Comment: @James_D I just added the code...

Comment: That should work just fine. Post a [MCVE].

Comment: here's the controller in minimal size... it doesn't load the second fxml file or at least clear the pane2...

Comment: the "fxml1.fxml" file reloads the whole view, I think the button click action is ignored once the "fxml1.fxml" file is loaded, as the view is having a fresh set of items...

Comment: Again, there is nothing wrong with the code you have posted. No-one can answer this as it stands. Did you even read the link in my previous comment?

Comment: ya I read it :) I've added more code... please check if it helps...

Comment: If you read it, there's something about the word "complete" you clearly don't understand.

Comment: wait, I'm working more on it...

Comment: Well I posted an answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

In your FXML, `pane2` is a child of `pane1`. So when you call `pane1.getChildren().clear()` you remove `pane2` from the UI completely. You need `pane1` and `pane2` not to have a parent/child relationship between them.

Depending on what you actually want to happen, something like

```xml
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="anchorPane" prefHeight="508.0" prefWidth="968.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controllers.HostelController">
    <children>
      <Pane fx:id="pane1" prefHeight="538.0" prefWidth="1014.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />

      <Button fx:id="hostelersBut" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="100.0" onAction="#hostelAction" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Hostel"> </Button>
      <Pane fx:id="pane2" layoutX="166.0" prefHeight="538.0" prefWidth="846.0" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```